# Open the French safe

Tags: mathematics, pattern

While walking in a small alley in Paris, you come across a safe.

The number pad looks like this :

[image]

There are things on the back of the safe too :

> "À l'aide du carré 3x3 ci-dessous et des nombres périphériques jaunes, déterminez le code du coffre-fort.
>   Entrez la combinaison trouvée sur le pavé numérique, puis appuyez sur 'Ouvrir'."
>   [image]

**What are the buttons you have to press on the number pad in order to open the safe ?**

Hint#1:

> The number behind the "?" isnt created using the same formula as the other white numbers. Despite this, there still are 4 ways to find it.

Comment: Google Translate: "Using the 3x3 square below and the yellow peripheral numbers, determine the safe code.
Enter the combination found on the numeric keypad, then press 'Open'. "